# Implementing ge1doot's parallax codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I'm having an issue implementing this (https://codepen.io/ge1doot/pen/oXWepr) codepen on my website. I want to replace the images, as one would. I've researched the millions of questions on drawing on canvas with javascript, but they all seem to point to either of two solutions: the CORS header and settings are resulting in a tainted canvas, or they don't have an image.onload function. CORS shouldn't be an issue for me, as the images are located on the same server, and I have an image.onload function. The altered code I am using is below.

This line in particular might be causing an issue:

```
var canvas  = ge1doot.canvas("canvas");
```

Though I have no idea. I'm not sure what it's actually doing, and through my hours of reading haven't exactly been able to figure it out. From my limited understanding, it may be doing the same thing as document.getElementById? But also, the canvas and background show up just fine when I change their colors in the css, it's just the images themselves that aren't showing up.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang"en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parallax.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>...</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" script src="parallax.js"></script>    
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="frame"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
  content-zooming: none;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  background: #fff;
}
#frame {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: -350px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px #fda;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
! function () {

    "use strict"; 

    function chromaKey(source, id) {
        // create new image
        var imgSource = new Image();
        //imgSource.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; Not sure if this should be commented out or not, but I think it should.
        imgSource.src = source;
        imgSource.onload = function () {
            // render image in canvas
            var jpg    = document.createElement('canvas');
            var w = jpg.width  = this.width;
            var h = jpg.height = this.height;
            var ctx = jpg.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w, h);
            // chroma Key
            var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),
                data = img.data;
            for (var i =0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                var r = data [i + 0];
                var g = data [i + 1];
                var b = data [i + 2];
                // make white transparent (rgb > 240, 240, 240)
                //if (r > 240 && g > 240 && b > 240) {  
                //  data[i + 3] = 0; 
                //} 
            }
            // create new transparent image
            var transparent = document.createElement('canvas');
            transparent.width = w;
            transparent.height = h;
            var ctx = transparent.getContext('2d');
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            images[id] = transparent;
        }
    }

    // draw parallax image
    function parallax (id, x, y) {
        var image = images[id];
        if (image) {
            ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
        }
    }

    // main loop
    function run() {
        // request next frame
        requestAnimationFrame(run);
        // clear screen
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // ease pointer
        pointer.cx += (pointer.x - pointer.cx) / 10;
        pointer.cy += (pointer.y - pointer.cy) / 10;
        var rx = -((canvas.width  / 2) - Math.max(15, Math.min(pointer.cx, canvas.width - 15))) / 7;
        var ry = -((canvas.height / 2) - Math.max(0, Math.min(pointer.cy, canvas.height - 5))) / 4.75;
        // parallax
        parallax(0, -20 + (rx / 2), -80 + (ry * 2)); 
        parallax(1, -40 + (rx / 2),  20 + (ry / 2)); 
        parallax(2, -20 + (rx / 3),  90 + (ry / 3)); 
        parallax(3, -20 - (rx / 2), 130 - (ry / 2)); 
        parallax(4,   0 - (rx / 1), 160 - (ry / 1));
        parallax(5, 240 - (rx * 2), 220 - (ry * 2));
    }

    // canvas
    var canvas  = ge1doot.canvas("canvas"); //I think this might have something to do with it? Not sure.
    var ctx     = canvas.ctx;
    // pointer
    var pointer = canvas.pointer;
    pointer.cx  = pointer.x = canvas.width / 2;
    pointer.cy  = 0;
    pointer.y = canvas.height;
    // images
    var images = [];
    // make jpg images transparent images
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 0);
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 1);
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 2);
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 3);
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 4);
    chromaKey("pengyu.jpg", 5);
    // zyva!
    run();

}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about this bit of code causing issue.

> var canvas  = ge1doot.canvas("canvas");

if you open the code pen you will see there is a javascript file being imported by code pen

> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222599/canvas-pointer.js?v=20150516

make sure you import them with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222599/canvas-pointer.js?v=20150516"></script>
```